# Range.Calculate() on background worksheet

Tags: excel, vsto

Is there any way to enforce Range.Calculate() on background (invisible) worksheet? This method seems to execute successfully, when the sheet is background, but it does nothing. No recalculation happens.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: It looks like range.Dirty(); range.Calculate();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, it's possible to reset Formula property like this:

```
            var formula = range.Formula;
            range.Formula = formula;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will happen if you are in Automatic mode, but not in Manual Mode
See http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsg.htm for more details

Note that there is a bug in Range.Dirty - it always acts on the active worksheet regardless of the worksheet your are referencing (so its not very useful!!)